# Website header issues

Tags: css, html, header

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Slayerk96/384vy/

My header is very wacky and unprofessional. I've been playing around with this header and I can't seem to get it right. Current header: (notice line between home and my name)

`Name(underlined)

                                            Home_blog_contact`

I have tried to position these items using css but the css won't adjust it right.

What I'm trying to make it look like:

`Name(bold and big no underline)                   Home Blog Contact(on same line)`

current css

```
.nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-color: 000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.Menu
{
 display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40%;
}
.Menu li{
  display: inline;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.Menu li a{
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Name {
  float: left;
}

.Menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

current html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <Title>Name</Title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="My Site Template.css">
    <script src="Page on googleapis.com"></script>
    <script src="styling my site.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class='nav'>
 <ul class='Menu'>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></li>
      </ul>     
 <h1 class='Name'>Name</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code in a fiddle so we can better visualize the problem. Also, you have a lowercase `name` in your CSS and an uppercase `Name` in the HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry but what's a fiddle.

Comment: Where are your `</a>` tags? I think it's time for you to change your text editor. Pick one that has syntax highlighting, will help you in your work

Comment: @user3907779 http://jsfiddle.net/. It's a website for posting code. You should make an account on there as well because it's very useful. SO users like it because it allows us to share code and troubleshoot.

Comment: @Jason actually it's faster to work and preview code on http://jsBin.com and it does not *stall* on-run like jsFiddle does quite often.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan meh I'm stuck in my ways XD. Either one is fine, though, especially for a problem that appears as trivial as this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Slayerk96/384vy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roko C. Buljan correctly noted, you forgot to close your anchor tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/9xh5L/

```
<div class='nav'>
    <ul class='Menu'>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>     
    <h1 class='Name'>Name</h1>
</div>
```

A good text editor (like Sublime Text) helps solve this problem by using syntax highlighting and autocompletion.

EDIT: you can also add `padding-top` to your .menu to make it align better vertically with .Name.